# Why do native speakers leave out articles in certain informal situations?

Tags: grammar

For example:

The airplane is **in air**. (why not *in THE air*?)

Walk **in gate**, please. (why not *in THE gate*?)

The items are **in room**. (why not *In THE room*?)

Are you still **in game**? (why not *in THE game*?)

---

I know newspapers and the like often omit articles, which is not the case here, since none of the sentences above were taken from headlines.

Comment: All of the above sentences sound unnatural to this US English speaker.  Do you have context for where you saw them?  The only one I might use is "in game" and there it would be written "in-game".

Comment: Agreed. None of those sentences sounds right to me. (Native American English speaker)

Comment: I saw most of them on an online game. Is it common to speak like that on online games?

Comment: How do you know the people who wrote them were native English speakers?

Comment: Because most of them are (supposedly) from English speaking countries like America and England. Also, I've heard the second example so many times by so many different people that I began to believe the version with "the" was actually the wrong one. Good to know it's not.

Comment: @Amandaa You'd be surprised to know how many programmers employed by video game companies are from non English speaking countries. Also game publishers and developers can be totally separate. A game may be published and distributed in the U.S. but developed in Japan.

Comment: Also, if people are playing a game, it may be that they are trying to communicate more quickly than grammatically. I'm no gamer, but it's not hard to imagine those folks seeing a word like "the" as three superfluous keystrokes that can be conveniently omitted.

Comment: Who says those are native speakers?? Sometimes, though, tech people will shorten things. However, planes are said to be airborne. All the others must take the.

Comment: *In game* is not weird at all if you're a gamer, but the rest sound strange to me.  My suspicion is that most speakers who find *in game* to be odd are not gamers.

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples are grammatically correct.

We sometimes omit articles headlines and other places where we want to keep the text brief, like on a sign, or on a bullet list. I wouldn't be surprised, for example, to see a sign reading "WALK IN GATE". Or to see a list of rules like, "Arrive on time", "Park in Area B", "Walk in gate", etc. I would be surprised to see that in normal text.

Sometimes we turn multiple words into a compound adjective. For example, "in-air" is an adjective used to describe airplanes. You can say, "We are trying to manage all the in-air planes." It would be unusual to say, "The plane is in-air", but maybe. Likewise, hotels talk about "in-room amenities", meaning, things that are in the individual rooms, as opposed to things in the lobby or some other common area.

Comment: I agree, though: walk-in gate might fly. Isn't airborne better than in-air?

Comment: @Lambie "walk-in gate" Sure, if there's some other kind of gate in context. "airborne better than in-air"? Probably. I think "use" is better than "utilize", too, but people don't always listen to me. :-)

Comment: I think I see "in-flight" much more often than "in-air", where the emphasis is more about the time period (during the flight) than about the plane's location (up in the air).

Comment: The aircraft are airborne. The passengers see in-flight movies.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Native English speaker.  The examples you have given are not correct English usage.  To me they sound the way non-English speakers might talk. You might consider finding a better source for your information.